# How to resize width of block wrapper on Susy

Tags: susy

I have an unfinished test project created by Susy\Sass\Compass:

https://github.com/gearmobile/portfolio/tree/master/travel

Width of the block wrapper `.wrapper` is 940px. But I need to 960px. What do I need for this?

Comment: Are you just asking which values to change in which files? Or is this question more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width of your "wrapper" in the .scss files
for example

```
.wrapper {
   @include container(960px);
}
```

Or you can define it in the susy global map

```
$susy: (
  container: 960px
)
```

Keep in mind that you can always declare a new container , lets say you had a page called trip.html you can always declare a new width for the wrapper

```
<body>
<div class="trip-wrapper">
<nav>Trio nav</nav>
<div>Trip content</div>
</div>
</body

 .wrapper {
       @include container(900px);
    }
```